# Drag behavior not working right?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to find the problem with the drag behavior setup that I have in my program, because it seems like the drag won't even activate. I'm using http://jsfiddle.net/da37B/317/ as the reference code for my program.

Here's the relevant code:

```
 vis.selectAll(".nodes")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "nodes")
        .attr("cx", function (d) {
            return xRange(d.x);
        })
        .attr("cy", function (d) {
            return yRange(d.y);
        })
        .attr("r", "10px")
        .attr("fill", "black")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")")
        .call(drag); <------
```

---

```
// Define drag beavior
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", dragmove);

function dragmove(d) {
    var x = d3.event.x;
    var y = d3.event.y;
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
}
```

And here's the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/4o5pch1q/1/

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't seem to contain the code you have in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you don't see any effect is that you have an error in your jsfiddle. Please check the console for such obvious things in the future.

Once the obvious error is fixed (including moving the definition of `drag` up so that it's defined before it's being used), the only thing that remains is to tell D3 how to get the origin of the element being dragged (otherwise the circle "jumps" on drag):

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function(d) { return d; })
    .on("drag", dragmove);
```

Complete demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4o5pch1q/4/).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there any reason why the demo I was using didn't need the origin function?

Comment: There wasn't anything else on the page -- you usually need the origin function if the mouse position doesn't give you the coordinates within the SVG as well. In your case, the SVG is offset because of the other elements.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I've noticed a problem with the dragging where if you drag a dot somewhere, let go of it, and then try to drag it again, it will jump to the original coordinate before the second drag attempt. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Argh, forgot to update the data on drag. I've fixed that and updated the link in the answer, sorry about that.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense too. Thanks